# Not able to import PagerSlidingTabStrip as library or project into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, pagerslidingtabstrip

I downloaded the zip of PagerSlidingTabStrip from [here].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwFDL.jpg) Extracted it but I am not able to import library into eclipse so that i can reference it. Please help. Following is screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just renaming the project name from library to Lib_PagerSlidingTabStrip and it was resolved.